# When does a Hermitian matrix have paired eigenvalues $(\lambda, -\lambda)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the sufficient and necessary conditions that an even sized and invertible Hermitian matrix to have its (real) eigenvalues $\lambda$ to come in pairs as in $(\lambda,-\lambda)$ with $\lambda$ having the same algebraic multiplicity as that of $-\lambda$. This is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1718821/64809).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One necessary and sufficient condition is that the characteristic polynomial is an even function.  Another is that (if your matrix is $A$) there exists a matrix $S$ with
$S^2 = I$ and $S A + A S = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain the second condition?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is diagonal, with the positive eigenvalues listed first and then the corresponding negative eigenvalues, so we can write it as a block matrix $\pmatrix{D & 0\cr 0 & -D}$.  Take $S = \pmatrix{0 & I\cr I & 0\cr}$.  Then $S^2 = \pmatrix{I & 0\cr 0 & I\cr}$ and $SA + AS = \pmatrix{0 & -D\cr D & 0\cr} + \pmatrix{0 & D\cr -D & 0\cr} = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$.  If $A$ is not diagonal, we diagonalize it so that $ A = U \pmatrix{D & 0\cr 0 & -D} U^{-1}$ and take $S = U \pmatrix{0 & I\cr I & 0\cr} U^{-1}$.

Comment: Right. I was dumb not to have realized that immediately. But, essentially, there is no criterion simpler than diagonalizing $A$. Is that right?

Comment: Computing determinants is in principle simpler than diagonalizing, though there may be numerical issues.  Take some random $\lambda$ and check if $\det(A-\lambda I) = \det(A + \lambda I)$.  If the characteristic polynomial is an even function these will be equal; if not, with probability $1$ they are different.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you expand on the numerical issues, specially whether these issues are more severe than diagonalization? Does Hermiticity impact the complexity comparison?